# How to return value of array of data from database in laravel 4.2?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have two table content,category

1-Category table is two column name and cat_id

2-content has column title,name,cat_id,id

3-Suppose content has three multiple cat_id

4 now I have to fetch name from that value which is in category table

Please see Attached photo of content and category table[image][image]

First pic is of content table

Second pic is of category table

```
public function AllStories()
{
    $cats = DB::table('content')
        ->join('category', 'content.Genres', '=', 'category.Genres')

        ->get();

    $AllStories=Content::all();

    return View::make('AlLStories')->with('AllStories',$AllStories)->with('cats',$cats);
}
```

now I have to fetch name from that value which is in category table

Comment: Rethink your schema, it's just wrong. You have to join tables with foreign keys, not comma-separated values.

Comment: We can't  find name of category from values separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

**Your table structure is wrong**

If you want to store Category information for a user you need to have pivot table where you can have category id against each content id.

Currently your content table have category as string since it's comma separated where as your category table have id as integer that's the reason you can not join them.

**Table Structure**

```
Author: id, author_name, ...

Category: id, category_title, Genre, ....

Content: id, title, ....

Content_Category: content_id, category_id

Author_Content: author_id, content_id
```

*other version of pivot table could be (depending on your requirement)*

```
Content_Category_Author: author_id, content_id, category_id
```

Now if you have relation like these you can do all kind of joins to fetch any require data.